# Docusign API - allow to redirect user to custom endpoint without clientUserId attribute

Tags: docusignapi

Currently, we are having two recipients to sign the DocuSign document.
we are redirecting one recipient to directly from our page to DocuSign to sign the document.
& other will get an email to sign the document.

Actually according to DocuSign API if we set clientUsetId it will not send the email to the recipient to sign the document.([Emails not sending when requesting signatures for DocuSign API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245442/emails-not-sending-when-requesting-signatures-for-docusign-api))

So We are setting clientUsetId for the first recipient & he is able to sign the DocuSign document from our page & he is not receiving any email which is expected.(https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#/definitions/envelopeDefinition)

The second recipient getting an email which expected but when he signs the document & singing has competed, recipient is on the standard DocuSign page.

here we want that recipient to redirect our website(endpoint with singing staus of the document) but from API documentation we not getting any feasible solution.

is there any way to redirect recipient after singing document(without using client Userid or from email)?

Answer (score 1):

Only [embedded recipients](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#EmbeddedSigning) can be redirected to the Sender specified url after they finish signing.

Make both the signers as embedded recipients and specify the [**embeddedRecipientStartURL**](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#core-recipient-parameters) for the second signer.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45084442/1219543) for more information.